# p:fileUpload method is not called in spring bean

Tags: ajax, spring, jsf, primefaces

This question concerns the upload and processing of CSV data in Spring Framework, using Primefaces upload, in order to create new entries in the database.

I've built my XHTML code on the template from Primefaces. When I click the Submit button, the uploadDevices method should be called, but I figured out that the method is never entered. When I remove the ajax="false" statement, the method is called, but throws a Nullpointer exception at the Inputstream, so apparently the file is not received.

Does anybody have advice on what to do? What does the ajax statement do, that prevents the method from being called?

Any help is very much appreciated.

devices.xhtml

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data" style="margin-bottom:20px">
    <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true" />

    <p:fileUpload value="#{fileUploadView.file}" ajax="false" mode="simple" skinSimple="true" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(csv)$/"/>

    <p:commandButton value="Submit" ajax="false" action="#{fileUploadView.uploadDevices()}" disabled="false" />
</h:form>
```

FileUploadView.java

```
@Component
@Scope("view")
public class FileUploadView {

private UploadedFile file;
// plus getter and setter

@Autowired
private DeviceService deviceService;

private Device device;

public void uploadDevices() { 
    final CSVParser parser = new CSVParserBuilder().withSeparator(',').withIgnoreQuotations(true).build();
    final BufferedReader fileReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(file.getInputstream()));
```

}

Comment: Does it work if you make it a jsf or cdi managed bean? And remove which ajax=false?

Comment: I tried to make it a [at]ManagedBean [at]ViewScoped, but that didn't do anything. When I remove the ajax="false" in p:commandButton, it enters the bean method but throws a Nullpointer Exception where file is mentioned first, so i suppose the is no file

Comment: `@ManagedBean` is not a CDI managed bean, that is `@Named` (with the corresponding scopes, pay attention to those), The `ajax="false"` on the commandButton is needed in this case, the one on the upload can be removed. And if you run in jsf development mode, any errors?

Answer (score 0):

Two common things people forget from the users guide. Don't forget "Faces Servlet" has to match your Servlet name of your Faces Servlet in web.xml

1. In your web.xml

   ```
   <!-- Primefaces required for FileUploads to work -->
   <filter>
      <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
      <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
   </filter>
   <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
      <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
   </filter-mapping>
   ```
2. In your pom.xml add Commons Upload dependency.

   ```
       <dependency>
           <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
           <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
           <version>1.3.3</version>
       </dependency>
   ```

Comment: I wrote a 'patch' for the showcase once to have these things visible in there. Not sure where it ended up, might be that I never submitted it. Or at least a reference to the documentation would be of great help

Comment: Thanks for you response. That did not fix my problem though.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so what solved my problem in the end was to add these methods in my Servlet Configurations, and now the Upload works just fine:

```
@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean facesServletRegistratiton() {
ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean(new FacesServlet(), new String[] { "*.xhtml" });
registration.setName("Faces Servlet");
registration.setLoadOnStartup(1);
return registration;
}

@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean facesUploadFilterRegistration() {
FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean(new FileUploadFilter(), facesServletRegistratiton());
registrationBean.setName("PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter");
registrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/*");
registrationBean.setDispatcherTypes(DispatcherType.FORWARD, DispatcherType.REQUEST);
return registrationBean;
}

@Bean
public ServletContextInitializer servletContextInitializer() {
return new ServletContextInitializer() {
    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    servletContext.setInitParameter("primefaces.UPLOADER", "commons");
    }
};
}
```